# Define the function if it's not being defined

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

```
if (typeof test1 !== "function") {
    const test1 = () => {
        return true
    }
}
```

I'm trying to evaluate javascript in the browser without defining a function repeatedly. However the above code is not defining the function, what is wrong?

Comment: `const` are block scoped - so that won't work - except within that `if` block of course

Comment: @Bravo I see, the problem is that I need to evaluate the same javascript code every time, so if I define the function without any condition wouldn't it be the same as redefining it each time?

Comment: yeah sure, I don't know, I was just telling you why your code didn't work, as you asked - didn't realise you wanted it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont declare `test1` inside `if` that will create a block scoped variable. Instead assign the value of `test1` inside `if` block.

JavaScript creates a block scoped variable if you declare the `test1` inside the if condition.

```js
// let test1 = 200; // Do only if you want to run the code single time
if (typeof test1 !== "function") {
    test1 = () => { 
        return true
    }
}
console.log(test1());
```

Comment: of course, if `test1` is not even `declared` this will result in a *global* function

Comment: But that wont be accessible outside the if statement since the scope of that variable resided only inside if. The possible solution would be declare the variable in global scope, update the variable inside the if and use it outside.

Comment: Would the test1 variable outside the if condition redefine itself if it's being previously defined?

Comment: @skygate yes it will. If the condition satisfies. I have updatred my example with that. Initially it was a number, which I have updated to a function.

Comment: @Nitheesh Is it possible to not define it if it's being previously defined?

Comment: @skygate your requirement was just the reverse of above statement right? "Define the function if it's not being defined"

Comment: @Nitheesh Yes, the thing is that I need to evaluate the same code each time into the browser. So if I write it in a way that assigns the variable with another value first each time, it'll be the same as redefining the function every time.

Comment: @skygate you can just comment the first line that makes the declaration. This will initialize and declare the variable inside the if block. This will make the code work as you expect.

Comment: @Nitheesh Thanks! That worked. Please add it to the answer.

Comment: @Nitheesh Sure!